# Html Code for Login in

Tags: html

I am looking for a code where an individual can log in and it ask for the temp password and then a new password is created by the user and that password is saved somewhere and it gets stored for the next log in. I have the below code and is not able to move further.

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <body>
    <title>Welcome to Infusionsoft Intranet</title>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="White">
    <table border="1" align="center" bgcolor="LIMEGreen">
    <tr>
    <td>User Name</td>
    <td><input typr="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Password</td>
    <td><input type="password"></td>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><button type="submit">Submit</button></td></table>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Instering Image</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p align="middle">
    <img src="C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Images\Infusion.jpg"></p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a long way to go. Look into html forms you dont have one and need one.  Then look into PHP form validation. and a crash course in mysql or another db.  Good Luck

Comment: There are multiple questions in this go through step by step if you get stuck post a question specific to the problem this question is to general.

Comment: I am new to this and i did find some code that is written on the top. however, i am not sure about PHP but will try and check how it works and what can be done. I did not get this sentence, "Look into html forms you don't have one and need one". i will try and get back if there is any questions.

Comment: Your inputs should be in a form.